# Check if AUDIO tag has a valid src using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio

So this is what I want.

If audio src is valid, then the audio shows controls.

If not then it doesn't show controls

But how in the world do I detect if audio src is valid?

Comment: what do you mean my `valid`

Comment: @TayyabFerozi I mean by if the audio is playable and doesn't return an error. I wanted to change this the audio says error on mobile and it annoys me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont actally need jQuery to check if it has been loaded correctly

**HTML:**

```
<audio onloadeddata="myOnLoadedData()" controls preload="auto">
  <source src="source here" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="source here" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

**JS:**

```
function myOnLoadedData() { ... do your thing, show controls }
```

You can also check if the audio can be played by using `oncanplay` attribute

Comment: no i need it to check it every time when the audio changes and then check if it has loaded. that's why I used jquery. I need code inside the .change function. this code executes when its successful but if its not successful there is not event listener for this and I need it to hide when it fails to load...

Comment: so you are changing the `src` of audio or what??

Comment: no i need it to hide if the audio changes and fails to load and show if it changes and loads successfully

Comment: Sorry? what do you mean my `audio changes`?? How can the audio change, I can't actually get you